# Why PowerShell Copy-Item cannot copy .csv file?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

Hi am newbee for powershell, but I have to use powershell to copy paste some csv file. I am wondering why I cannot copy csv file by using Copy-Item?
When I use variable $csv the Copy-Item failed, but if I used $txt it runs ok.

```
$csv = "C:\Gen\Test\FacilitiesLog\20210616.csv"
$txt = "C:\Gen\Test\FacilitiesLog\20210616.txt"

$PathPasteTo = "P:\Test\TestProfiles"

$x = Copy-Item $csv -Destination $PathPasteTo -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
if($x){
 "succeed"
 }
 else{
 "failed"
 }
```

Comment: Remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and run it again. Powershell will generally tell you why. If you get an error you're not sure on, add it to your question

Comment: You can also use `Try { Copy-Item ... } Catch [ExceptionName] { "failed" }` instead of using `-passthrough` and an `if` statement. It will let you catch only exceptions that you expect instead of squashing all the information.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you for the reply. I just used Catch [ExceptionName]. It says  Copy-Item : Cannot find path $csv = 'C:\Gen\Test\FacilitiesLog\20210616.csv' because it does not exist. but I am pretty sure the csv file is at correct location. it is very strange

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I have found the issue. The csv file we have here has two suffix .csv. The issue has been solved. Thank you.